# How to add hyphen after every 4th character to a string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, format

I using card.io for scanning my credit/debit card. When the scan is completed I receive string like `'3456789023456789'`. I am setting this string value to my textfield. Now I want that when setting the string value to textfield it should appear in this format `'3456-7890-2345-6789'`.

Comment: Remember that not all credit cards are the 4x4 format.  AmEx is a primary example.  Be sure to check the card type before formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"3456789023456789"];
int four = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    [str insertString:@"-" atIndex:(i==0 ? four : four*(i+1)+i )];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `NSMutableString` and use the function

```
- (void)insertString:(NSString *)aString atIndex:(NSUInteger)loc;
```

example `[myMutableString insertString:@"-" atIndex:multiplesOfFour]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to insert hiphen(-) after every forth character:

```
NSMutableString *requiredString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < string.length; i = i+4) {
    NSString *subString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 4)];
    if(i+4 < string.length) {
        [requiredString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-", subString]];
    }
    else {
        [requiredString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subString]];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be wrong with last value : 3456-7890-2345-6789-

Answer (score 0):

```
for( NSInteger i = 3 ; i < aMutableString.length ; i += 4  ) {
    [aMutableString insertString:@"-" atIndex: i + i/4 ] ;
}
```